# how to get a java date in "packed byte" format?

Tags: java, smf-forum

I'm trying to manually enter a forum user into an smf database but can't seem to figure out how to get the current date in the proper format, which I found out is something called "packed byte".

can anyone point me to some info to help out?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicstg/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.tg.doc/ctgzos/smfdate.html

Comment: ^I'm talking about getting a date in java in proper format for an smf database entry. (as I said in my question)

Comment: Is there something that you do not understand in IBM documentation? Do you have trouble implementing algorithm in Java or?

Comment: @SamiKorhonen having trouble implementing it in java, I've only ever retrieved the date in simpledateformat

Comment: Simple Machines Forums != IBM CICS !!!!

Comment: I don't know anything about Simple Machines Forum but I presume it uses a MySQL database which has a regular MySQL datetime column

Answer (score 0):

According IBM's SFM Wiki the 'byte packed date format' is defined [as follows](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicstg/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.tg.doc/ctgzos/smfdate.html):

```
0x[0C][YY][DDD][+]
     where:
       C = centuries since 1900 (e.g. 1 for the 21st century)
      YY = year
     DDD = day (1 for Jan. 1 366 for Dec. 31)
       + = 0xC (Hardcoded)
```

Example: Aug. 31. 2014 = 0x01 14 244 C

In Java you could use the `java.util.Calendar` to create a hex string containing all required values and use `Long.valueOf(...,16)` to get a number out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted the spec you linked in comments correctly - you can use a combination of String formatting and parsing to get what you need. I chose to use String formatting because although the output expected is a base-16 number, it appears to encode values as base-10 values within the base-16 number.

```
Calendar toPack = Calendar.getInstance(); 

int century = (toPack.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900) / 100; 
int year = toPack.get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100; 
int dayOfYear = toPack.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); 

String packedDate = String.format("%02d%02d%03dC", century, year, dayOfYear);
int packed = Integer.parseInt(packedDate, 16); 

System.out.printf("0x%x%n", packed);
```

Output:

```
0x114238c
```